# Python script to collect NWS gridpoint forecast data (JSON) and push it into MariaDB

Tags: python, mysql, json

This script is my first-ever attempt at writing anything in python.  Though I have an electrical engineering background and therefore got a little programming education in college, it was fairly limited and I am definitely no big-time coder, so much of this script may be very rudimentary.  I've never touched a JSON file before, and I just installed and configured my first MariaDB database last week, though I do have a little SQL experience with other relational databases.  I figured I'd post this here just for general thoughts and suggestions on how I can do better in the future, both with revisions to this script and with python scripting in general.

This script reads in the current point forecast for my local gridpoint from the National Weather Service API.  It then grabs the forecast quantities that I am most interested in, which mainly mirror the data that I can collect with my Davis Vantage Pro2 weather station (which is writing minute-by-minute values into a different table in this same MariaDB database via a Meteobridge Pro).  I will be running this script every couple hours to try to make sure I pick up every forecast run (there are generally around four runs per day, I believe), so the script also checks the database for the existence of forecast data with the same model-run timestamp before it writes everything.

The script seems to do what I am after.  I have just a little basic checking built-in to make sure I'm staying on the correct forecast period with all of my different parameters, as well as the aforementioned check for the same data already being present.  So, beyond that, I'm open to suggestions and guidance on good form and practice in python scripting.  This script and the MariaDB are running on a Fedora 34 server with 6 spinning hard drives in RAID5 and a caching enterprise SSD with a Ryzen 9 3950X CPU that is my emby media server, so it was mostly sitting idle when I'm not watching a movie...it needed something to do the rest of the time.

```
import noaa_sdk
import json
import geojson
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from dateutil import tz
from array import *
from noaa_sdk import NOAA
import re
import mariadb

# Setup Times

from_zone = tz.tzutc()
to_zone = tz.tzlocal()
curr_time = datetime.now()
curr_time = curr_time.replace(tzinfo=to_zone) # Make curr_time aware of time zone
next_hour = curr_time.replace(second=0, microsecond=0, minute=0) + timedelta(hours=1) # Find the first forecast time that we'll be using later


# Initialize intermediate forecast arrays

tempi_fcst = [[0,0,0]]
dewpi_fcst = [[0,0,0]]
relhi_fcst = [[0,0,0]]
windi_fcst = [[0,0,0]]
wdiri_fcst = [[0,0,0]]
propi_fcst = [[0,0,0]]
qprfi_fcst = [[0,0,0]]
skyci_fcst = [[0,0,0]]

# Obtain current NWS forecast data

n = NOAA()
full_data = n.points_forecast(40.1585, -103.2036, type='forecastGridData')

# Determine Forecast Time and Figure out how long this forecast is good for

forecast_time = full_data['properties'].get('updateTime')[:19]
forecast_time = datetime.strptime(str(forecast_time), '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
forecast_time = forecast_time.replace(tzinfo=from_zone)
forecast_time = forecast_time.astimezone(to_zone)
valid_time = full_data['properties'].get('validTimes')[:19]
valid_time = datetime.strptime(str(valid_time), '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
valid_time = valid_time.replace(tzinfo=from_zone)
valid_time = valid_time.astimezone(to_zone)
vd = re.compile(r"(?<=P)(.*?)(?=DT)")
vh = re.compile(r"(?<=DT)(.*?)(?=H)")
valid_days = vd.search(full_data['properties'].get('validTimes'))
valid_days = int(valid_days.group())
valid_hours = vh.search(full_data['properties'].get('validTimes'))
valid_hours = int(valid_hours.group())
valid_time = valid_time + timedelta(hours=valid_hours,days=valid_days)
fdelta = valid_time - next_hour
forecast_hours = fdelta.days * 24 + fdelta.seconds // 3600

#######################################################
# Build the Temperature Forecast Array                #
#######################################################

forecast_period = 0

# First, write into the initial row of the array
tempi_fcst[forecast_period][0] = (full_data['properties']['temperature']['values'][forecast_period].get('value') * (9/5)) + 32  # Convert temperature to Fahrenheit and push into array
tempi_fcst[forecast_period][1] = full_data['properties']['temperature']['values'][forecast_period].get('validTime')[:19]  # Read the UTC time for the current forecast period
tempi_fcst[forecast_period][1] = datetime.strptime(str(tempi_fcst[forecast_period][1]), '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')  # Convert NWS formatted time to python DateTime value
tempi_fcst[forecast_period][1] = tempi_fcst[forecast_period][1].replace(tzinfo=from_zone)  # Tell the DateTime value that it is in UTC
tempi_fcst[forecast_period][1] = tempi_fcst[forecast_period][1].astimezone(to_zone)  # Convert the DateTime value to local time zone
tempi_fcst[forecast_period][2] = full_data['properties']['temperature']['values'][forecast_period].get('validTime')[28:29]  # Push valid hours field into array
forecast_period += 1  # Increment period index

while forecast_period < (len(full_data['properties']['temperature']['values']) - 1):  # Fill in the rest of the array with all of the temperature forecast periods from NWS
    tempi_fcst.append([0,0,0])  # Append the next row that we're going to write into
    tempi_fcst[forecast_period][0] = (full_data['properties']['temperature']['values'][forecast_period].get('value') * (9/5)) + 32
    tempi_fcst[forecast_period][1] = full_data['properties']['temperature']['values'][forecast_period].get('validTime')[:19]
    tempi_fcst[forecast_period][1] = datetime.strptime(str(tempi_fcst[forecast_period][1]), '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
    tempi_fcst[forecast_period][1] = tempi_fcst[forecast_period][1].replace(tzinfo=from_zone)
    tempi_fcst[forecast_period][1] = tempi_fcst[forecast_period][1].astimezone(to_zone)
    tempi_fcst[forecast_period][2] = full_data['properties']['temperature']['values'][forecast_period].get('validTime')[28:29]
    forecast_period += 1
    
    
#######################################################
# Build the Dewpoint Forecast Array                   #
#######################################################

forecast_period = 0

dewpi_fcst[forecast_period][0] = (full_data['properties']['dewpoint']['values'][forecast_period].get('value') * (9/5)) + 32
dewpi_fcst[forecast_period][1] = full_data['properties']['dewpoint']['values'][forecast_period].get('validTime')[:19]
dewpi_fcst[forecast_period][1] = datetime.strptime(str(dewpi_fcst[forecast_period][1]), '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
dewpi_fcst[forecast_period][1] = dewpi_fcst[forecast_period][1].replace(tzinfo=from_zone)
dewpi_fcst[forecast_period][1] = dewpi_fcst[forecast_period][1].astimezone(to_zone)
dewpi_fcst[forecast_period][2] = full_data['properties']['dewpoint']['values'][forecast_period].get('validTime')[28:29]
forecast_period += 1

while forecast_period < (len(full_data['properties']['dewpoint']['values']) - 1):
    dewpi_fcst.append([0,0,0])
    dewpi_fcst[forecast_period][0] = (full_data['properties']['dewpoint']['values'][forecast_period].get('value') * (9/5)) + 32
    dewpi_fcst[forecast_period][1] = full_data['properties']['dewpoint']['values'][forecast_period].get('validTime')[:19]
    dewpi_fcst[forecast_period][1] = datetime.strptime(str(dewpi_fcst[forecast_period][1]), '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
    dewpi_fcst[forecast_period][1] = dewpi_fcst[forecast_period][1].replace(tzinfo=from_zone)
    dewpi_fcst[forecast_period][1] = dewpi_fcst[forecast_period][1].astimezone(to_zone)
    dewpi_fcst[forecast_period][2] = full_data['properties']['dewpoint']['values'][forecast_period].get('validTime')[28:29]
    forecast_period += 1
    
    
#######################################################
# Build the Relative Humidity Forecast Array          #
#######################################################

forecast_period = 0

relhi_fcst[forecast_period][0] = full_data['properties']['relativeHumidity']['values'][forecast_period].get('value')
relhi_fcst[forecast_period][1] = full_data['properties']['relativeHumidity']['values'][forecast_period].get('validTime')[:19]
relhi_fcst[forecast_period][1] = datetime.strptime(str(relhi_fcst[forecast_period][1]), '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
relhi_fcst[forecast_period][1] = relhi_fcst[forecast_period][1].replace(tzinfo=from_zone)
relhi_fcst[forecast_period][1] = relhi_fcst[forecast_period][1].astimezone(to_zone)
relhi_fcst[forecast_period][2] = full_data['properties']['relativeHumidity']['values'][forecast_period].get('validTime')[28:29]
forecast_period += 1

while forecast_period < (len(full_data['properties']['relativeHumidity']['values']) - 1):
    relhi_fcst.append([0,0,0])
    relhi_fcst[forecast_period][0] = full_data['properties']['relativeHumidity']['values'][forecast_period].get('value')
    relhi_fcst[forecast_period][1] = full_data['properties']['relativeHumidity']['values'][forecast_period].get('validTime')[:19]
    relhi_fcst[forecast_period][1] = datetime.strptime(str(relhi_fcst[forecast_period][1]), '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
    relhi_fcst[forecast_period][1] = relhi_fcst[forecast_period][1].replace(tzinfo=from_zone)
    relhi_fcst[forecast_period][1] = relhi_fcst[forecast_period][1].astimezone(to_zone)
    relhi_fcst[forecast_period][2] = full_data['properties']['relativeHumidity']['values'][forecast_period].get('validTime')[28:29]
    forecast_period += 1


#######################################################
# Build the Wind Speed Forecast Array                 #
#######################################################

forecast_period = 0

windi_fcst[forecast_period][0] = full_data['properties']['windSpeed']['values'][forecast_period].get('value')
windi_fcst[forecast_period][1] = full_data['properties']['windSpeed']['values'][forecast_period].get('validTime')[:19]
windi_fcst[forecast_period][1] = datetime.strptime(str(windi_fcst[forecast_period][1]), '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
windi_fcst[forecast_period][1] = windi_fcst[forecast_period][1].replace(tzinfo=from_zone)
windi_fcst[forecast_period][1] = windi_fcst[forecast_period][1].astimezone(to_zone)
windi_fcst[forecast_period][2] = full_data['properties']['windSpeed']['values'][forecast_period].get('validTime')[28:29]
forecast_period += 1

while forecast_period < (len(full_data['properties']['windSpeed']['values']) - 1):
    windi_fcst.append([0,0,0])
    windi_fcst[forecast_period][0] = full_data['properties']['windSpeed']['values'][forecast_period].get('value')
    windi_fcst[forecast_period][1] = full_data['properties']['windSpeed']['values'][forecast_period].get('validTime')[:19]
    windi_fcst[forecast_period][1] = datetime.strptime(str(windi_fcst[forecast_period][1]), '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
    windi_fcst[forecast_period][1] = windi_fcst[forecast_period][1].replace(tzinfo=from_zone)
    windi_fcst[forecast_period][1] = windi_fcst[forecast_period][1].astimezone(to_zone)
    windi_fcst[forecast_period][2] = full_data['properties']['windSpeed']['values'][forecast_period].get('validTime')[28:29]
    forecast_period += 1
    
    
#######################################################
# Build the Wind Direction Forecast Array             #
#######################################################

forecast_period = 0

wdiri_fcst[forecast_period][0] = full_data['properties']['windDirection']['values'][forecast_period].get('value')
wdiri_fcst[forecast_period][1] = full_data['properties']['windDirection']['values'][forecast_period].get('validTime')[:19]
wdiri_fcst[forecast_period][1] = datetime.strptime(str(wdiri_fcst[forecast_period][1]), '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
wdiri_fcst[forecast_period][1] = wdiri_fcst[forecast_period][1].replace(tzinfo=from_zone)
wdiri_fcst[forecast_period][1] = wdiri_fcst[forecast_period][1].astimezone(to_zone)
wdiri_fcst[forecast_period][2] = full_data['properties']['windDirection']['values'][forecast_period].get('validTime')[28:29]
forecast_period += 1

while forecast_period < (len(full_data['properties']['windDirection']['values']) - 1):
    wdiri_fcst.append([0,0,0])
    wdiri_fcst[forecast_period][0] = full_data['properties']['windDirection']['values'][forecast_period].get('value')
    wdiri_fcst[forecast_period][1] = full_data['properties']['windDirection']['values'][forecast_period].get('validTime')[:19]
    wdiri_fcst[forecast_period][1] = datetime.strptime(str(wdiri_fcst[forecast_period][1]), '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
    wdiri_fcst[forecast_period][1] = wdiri_fcst[forecast_period][1].replace(tzinfo=from_zone)
    wdiri_fcst[forecast_period][1] = wdiri_fcst[forecast_period][1].astimezone(to_zone)
    wdiri_fcst[forecast_period][2] = full_data['properties']['windDirection']['values'][forecast_period].get('validTime')[28:29]
    forecast_period += 1

# Leftover bits from how I was going to do the forecasts, just in case I want to go back and revisit anything here

# period = len(wdiri_fcst) - 1
# count = 0
# 
# while wdiri_fcst[period][1] > curr_time:
#     count += 1
#     period -= 1
# 
# rows, cols = (count, 3)
# wdir_fcst =[]
# for i in range(rows):
#     col = []
#     for j in range(cols):
#         col.append(0)
#     wdir_fcst.append(col)
#     
# iperiod = period + 1
# period = 0
# 
# while period <= (count - 1):
#     wdir_fcst[period][0] = wdiri_fcst[iperiod][0]
#     wdir_fcst[period][1] = wdiri_fcst[iperiod][1]
#     wdir_fcst[period][2] = wdiri_fcst[iperiod][2]
#     period += 1
#     iperiod += 1
    
    
#######################################################
# Build the probabilityOfPrecipitation Forecast Array #
#######################################################

forecast_period = 0

propi_fcst[forecast_period][0] = full_data['properties']['probabilityOfPrecipitation']['values'][forecast_period].get('value')
propi_fcst[forecast_period][1] = full_data['properties']['probabilityOfPrecipitation']['values'][forecast_period].get('validTime')[:19]
propi_fcst[forecast_period][1] = datetime.strptime(str(propi_fcst[forecast_period][1]), '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
propi_fcst[forecast_period][1] = propi_fcst[forecast_period][1].replace(tzinfo=from_zone)
propi_fcst[forecast_period][1] = propi_fcst[forecast_period][1].astimezone(to_zone)
propi_fcst[forecast_period][2] = full_data['properties']['probabilityOfPrecipitation']['values'][forecast_period].get('validTime')[28:29]
forecast_period += 1

while forecast_period < (len(full_data['properties']['probabilityOfPrecipitation']['values']) - 1):
    propi_fcst.append([0,0,0])
    propi_fcst[forecast_period][0] = full_data['properties']['probabilityOfPrecipitation']['values'][forecast_period].get('value')
    propi_fcst[forecast_period][1] = full_data['properties']['probabilityOfPrecipitation']['values'][forecast_period].get('validTime')[:19]
    propi_fcst[forecast_period][1] = datetime.strptime(str(propi_fcst[forecast_period][1]), '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
    propi_fcst[forecast_period][1] = propi_fcst[forecast_period][1].replace(tzinfo=from_zone)
    propi_fcst[forecast_period][1] = propi_fcst[forecast_period][1].astimezone(to_zone)
    propi_fcst[forecast_period][2] = full_data['properties']['probabilityOfPrecipitation']['values'][forecast_period].get('validTime')[28:29]
    forecast_period += 1
    
    
#######################################################
# Build the quantitativePrecipitation Forecast Array  #
#######################################################

forecast_period = 0

qprfi_fcst[forecast_period][0] = full_data['properties']['quantitativePrecipitation']['values'][forecast_period].get('value')
qprfi_fcst[forecast_period][1] = full_data['properties']['quantitativePrecipitation']['values'][forecast_period].get('validTime')[:19]
qprfi_fcst[forecast_period][1] = datetime.strptime(str(qprfi_fcst[forecast_period][1]), '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
qprfi_fcst[forecast_period][1] = qprfi_fcst[forecast_period][1].replace(tzinfo=from_zone)
qprfi_fcst[forecast_period][1] = qprfi_fcst[forecast_period][1].astimezone(to_zone)
qprfi_fcst[forecast_period][2] = full_data['properties']['quantitativePrecipitation']['values'][forecast_period].get('validTime')[28:29]
forecast_period += 1

while forecast_period < (len(full_data['properties']['quantitativePrecipitation']['values']) - 1):
    qprfi_fcst.append([0,0,0])
    qprfi_fcst[forecast_period][0] = full_data['properties']['quantitativePrecipitation']['values'][forecast_period].get('value')
    qprfi_fcst[forecast_period][1] = full_data['properties']['quantitativePrecipitation']['values'][forecast_period].get('validTime')[:19]
    qprfi_fcst[forecast_period][1] = datetime.strptime(str(qprfi_fcst[forecast_period][1]), '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
    qprfi_fcst[forecast_period][1] = qprfi_fcst[forecast_period][1].replace(tzinfo=from_zone)
    qprfi_fcst[forecast_period][1] = qprfi_fcst[forecast_period][1].astimezone(to_zone)
    qprfi_fcst[forecast_period][2] = full_data['properties']['quantitativePrecipitation']['values'][forecast_period].get('validTime')[28:29]
    forecast_period += 1
    
    
#######################################################
# Build the Sky Cover Forecast Array                  #
#######################################################

forecast_period = 0

skyci_fcst[forecast_period][0] = full_data['properties']['skyCover']['values'][forecast_period].get('value')
skyci_fcst[forecast_period][1] = full_data['properties']['skyCover']['values'][forecast_period].get('validTime')[:19]
skyci_fcst[forecast_period][1] = datetime.strptime(str(skyci_fcst[forecast_period][1]), '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
skyci_fcst[forecast_period][1] = skyci_fcst[forecast_period][1].replace(tzinfo=from_zone)
skyci_fcst[forecast_period][1] = skyci_fcst[forecast_period][1].astimezone(to_zone)
skyci_fcst[forecast_period][2] = full_data['properties']['skyCover']['values'][forecast_period].get('validTime')[28:29]
forecast_period += 1

while forecast_period < (len(full_data['properties']['skyCover']['values']) - 1):
    skyci_fcst.append([0,0,0])
    skyci_fcst[forecast_period][0] = full_data['properties']['skyCover']['values'][forecast_period].get('value')
    skyci_fcst[forecast_period][1] = full_data['properties']['skyCover']['values'][forecast_period].get('validTime')[:19]
    skyci_fcst[forecast_period][1] = datetime.strptime(str(skyci_fcst[forecast_period][1]), '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
    skyci_fcst[forecast_period][1] = skyci_fcst[forecast_period][1].replace(tzinfo=from_zone)
    skyci_fcst[forecast_period][1] = skyci_fcst[forecast_period][1].astimezone(to_zone)
    skyci_fcst[forecast_period][2] = full_data['properties']['skyCover']['values'][forecast_period].get('validTime')[28:29]
    forecast_period += 1
    
    
#######################################################
# Build the master forecast array                     #
#######################################################

rows, cols = (forecast_hours, 9)  # One row for every hour of forecast validity beyond the current time, with a column each for the forecast period DateTime and each forecast quantity
forecast = []
for i in range(rows):
    col = []
    for j in range(cols):
        col.append(0)
    forecast.append(col)

# Initialize all of the period indices
period = 0
tempi_per = 0
dewpi_per = 0
relhi_per = 0
windi_per = 0
wdiri_per = 0
propi_per = 0
qprfi_per = 0
skyci_per = 0
print("Forecast Array") # Print a header for diagnostic purposes

while period < (forecast_hours - 1): # Make sure we haven't run out past the end of our forecast validity
    forecast[period][0] = next_hour + timedelta(hours=period)  # Write the current forecast period DateTime into the array, starting with the next hour that will occur after the current time
    while (tempi_fcst[tempi_per][1] < forecast[period][0]) and (tempi_per < (len(tempi_fcst) - 1)):  # Run up the Temperature forecast array's period index until the temperature forecast period is equal to or just higher than the current forecast period
        tempi_per += 1
    if tempi_fcst[tempi_per][1] == forecast[period][0]:  # If the Temperature forecast includes a period that coincides with the current forecast period, then use this temperature period
        forecast[period][1] = '{:6.2f}'.format(tempi_fcst[tempi_per][0])  # Write nicely-formatted values that match the formatting of the database table columns into the big forecast array
    else:  # However, if the Temperature forecast contained a >1 hr interval and jumped past the current forecast period, stay with the previous temperature period for this go-round
        forecast[period][1] = '{:6.2f}'.format(tempi_fcst[tempi_per - 1][0])
    while (dewpi_fcst[dewpi_per][1] < forecast[period][0]) and (dewpi_per < (len(dewpi_fcst) - 1)):  # Continue as with Temperature
        dewpi_per += 1
    if dewpi_fcst[dewpi_per][1] == forecast[period][0]:
        forecast[period][2] = '{:6.2f}'.format(dewpi_fcst[dewpi_per][0])
    else:
        forecast[period][2] = '{:6.2f}'.format(dewpi_fcst[dewpi_per - 1][0])
    while (relhi_fcst[relhi_per][1] < forecast[period][0]) and (relhi_per < (len(relhi_fcst) - 1)):
        relhi_per += 1
    if relhi_fcst[relhi_per][1] == forecast[period][0]:
        forecast[period][3] = '{:3d}'.format(relhi_fcst[relhi_per][0])
    else:
        forecast[period][3] = '{:3d}'.format(relhi_fcst[relhi_per - 1][0])
    while (windi_fcst[windi_per][1] < forecast[period][0]) and (windi_per < (len(windi_fcst) - 1)):
        windi_per += 1
    if windi_fcst[windi_per][1] == forecast[period][0]:
        forecast[period][4] = '{:7.3f}'.format(windi_fcst[windi_per][0])
    else:
        forecast[period][4] = '{:7.3f}'.format(windi_fcst[windi_per - 1][0])
    while (wdiri_fcst[wdiri_per][1] < forecast[period][0]) and (wdiri_per < (len(wdiri_fcst) - 1)):
        wdiri_per += 1
    if wdiri_fcst[wdiri_per][1] == forecast[period][0]:
        forecast[period][5] = '{:3d}'.format(wdiri_fcst[wdiri_per][0])
    else:
        forecast[period][5] = '{:3d}'.format(wdiri_fcst[wdiri_per - 1][0])
    while (propi_fcst[propi_per][1] < forecast[period][0]) and (propi_per < (len(propi_fcst) - 1)):
        propi_per += 1
    if propi_fcst[propi_per][1] == forecast[period][0]:
        forecast[period][6] = '{:3d}'.format(propi_fcst[propi_per][0])
    else:
        forecast[period][6] = '{:3d}'.format(propi_fcst[propi_per - 1][0])
    while (qprfi_fcst[qprfi_per][1] < forecast[period][0]) and (qprfi_per < (len(qprfi_fcst) - 1)):
        qprfi_per += 1
    if qprfi_fcst[qprfi_per][1] == forecast[period][0]:
        forecast[period][7] = '{:6.3f}'.format(qprfi_fcst[qprfi_per][0] / float(qprfi_fcst[qprfi_per][2])) # Quantitative Precip Forecast is usually spread over multiple hours, so divide the forecast amount by the number of valid hours for this period
    else:
        forecast[period][7] = '{:6.3f}'.format(qprfi_fcst[qprfi_per - 1][0] / float(qprfi_fcst[qprfi_per - 1][2]))
    while (skyci_fcst[skyci_per][1] < forecast[period][0]) and (skyci_per < (len(skyci_fcst) - 1)):
        skyci_per += 1
    if skyci_fcst[skyci_per][1] == forecast[period][0]:
        forecast[period][8] = '{:3d}'.format(skyci_fcst[skyci_per][0])
    else:
        forecast[period][8] = '{:3d}'.format(skyci_fcst[skyci_per - 1][0])
    print("[ " + str(forecast[period][0]) + " , {a:s} , {b:s} , {c:s} , {d:s} , {e:s} , {f:s} , {g:s} , {h:s} ]".format(a=forecast[period][1], b=forecast[period][2], c=forecast[period][3], d=forecast[period][4], e=forecast[period][5], f=forecast[period][6], g=forecast[period][7], h=forecast[period][8]))  # For troubleshooting, print out the row we just made
    period += 1


# Connect to the database

try:
    conn = mariadb.connect(
        user="wx_user",
        port=3306,
        database="weatherdb"

    )
except mariadb.Error as e:
    print(f"Error connecting to MariaDB Platform: {e}")
    sys.exit(1)

cur = conn.cursor()
conn.autocommit = True

# Write the current forecast data run into the database if it does not already exist there

cur.execute("SELECT `fcst_period`,`fcst_time` FROM `forecast` WHERE `fcst_time`=?", (str(forecast_time)[:19],)) # Check to see if the current forecast run is already in the database
if cur.fetchall() == []:  # If there are no matching results, push the current forecast run into the database
    period = 0
    while period < (forecast_hours - 1):
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO `forecast` (`fcst_period`, `temp`, `dewp`, `relh`, `wind`, `wdir`, `prop`, `qprf`, `skyc`, `fcst_ID`, `fcst_time`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 'NWS-API', ?)",(str(forecast[period][0])[:19], forecast[period][1], forecast[period][2], forecast[period][3], forecast[period][4], forecast[period][5], forecast[period][6], forecast[period][7], forecast[period][8], str(forecast_time)[:19]))  # This forecast comes from the National Weather Service API, so identify it as such and timestamp everything with the forecast's overall timestamp
        period += 1
```

Edit:  I should mention that I did snip out the database server address and password.  They are in the working version.